# Power Query help to transform row into table

Tags: powerbi, powerquery

Need to convert below input table to out table using Power Bi query

From:

[image]

To:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try this

click select key column

transform .. pivot column...

values column: Final

advanced options: don't aggregate

right click extra column and remove

```
let  Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
#"Pivoted Column" = Table.Pivot(Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source, {{"key", type text}}, "en-US"), List.Distinct(Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source, {{"key", type text}}, "en-US")[key]), "key", "Final")
in  #"Pivoted Column"
```

[image]